# KineticJS - Performance Difference Between Kinetic.Group.listening() and Individual Kinetic.Node.listening()

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is there any performance difference between this:

```
var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({ listening: false }),
    rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({ listening: false }),
    group = new Kinetic.Group;

group.add( rect1 );
group.add( rect2 );
```

... and this:

```
var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect,
    rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect,
    group = new Kinetic.Group({ listening: false });

group.add( rect1 );
group.add( rect2 );
```

If so, why?